# Puzzle Hunt 02: Echoes of Change

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, crossword-clues

---

<sub>This is part two in my clichéd treasure island puzzle series. The story carries directly on from [part one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90823/puzzle-hunt-01-a-cliched-treasure-map).</sub>

---

You take an incredulous look at the map.

<sub>spoiler for part one</sub>

> "X Marks the spot!?"

"That's a bit of a cliché. "Do you think that means Cross-bone Cliffs?"

"Not a chance." replies your Dad. "That place was barren. Nothing there other than rocks and bird crap. I think the map is just messing with you. Leave it."

But you can't leave it, can you? What sort of story would this be if you just ignored it and binned the map? Terrible. Through bribery and alcohol you convince your best mate, Frank, and his sister, Joan, to join you on an expedition to the island, which just so happens to be within sailing distance, and Joan just so happens to own a yacht. Convenient.

You land on the north-east of the island, on the beach by the echo caves. The three of you trudge up to the mouth of the cave and peer into the uninviting blackness. The caves disappear steeply down into the side of a hill, heading inland. You stand at the caves mouth and decide to test the relevance of the name. You holler into the void: "BOOM!" The cave seems to swallow up the shout, but a few seconds later a deep echo returns.

"BOOT!"

"That's odd. Not exactly what I said, but I suppose close enough."

"JOAN!" shouts Joan. A little egotistically.

"LOAN!" Comes the echo.

"Huh." She muses. "Strange."

It seems clear that the cave is twisting your words. But why? Is it trying to tell you something? To determine what it is saying, you shout different words and record the echo.

The clues below hint to what was spoken and what was echoed. Can you figure out the specifics and determine what the cave is trying to say?

\begin{array} {|l|l|}\hline \textbf { Shout }  & \textbf { Echo }
  \\ \hline \text { Past Curfew } & \text { Spike Drink }
  \\ \hline \text { Vaccine Injection } & \text { Chimney Deposit }
  \\ \hline \text { Hearing Organs } & \text { Red Planet }
  \\ \hline \text { First Prize } & \text { Castrate Horse }
  \\ \hline \text { Heavenly Body } & \text { Fly High }
  \\ \hline \text { High Temperature } & \text { Without Ice }
  \\ \hline \text { Road Curve } & \text { Wrap Tightly }
  \\ \hline \text { Bacon Fat } & \text { Touch Down }
  \\ \hline \text { Buy and... } & \text { Aquatic Clapper }
  \\ \hline \text { Supply Meal } & \text { Ward Off }
  \\ \hline \text { Money Maker } & \text { Watch Temporarily }
  \\ \hline \text { Sharp Taste } & \text { Piece of }
  \\ \hline \text { Stocking stuffers } & \text { Snooker Surface }
  \\ \hline \text { Carnival attraction } & \text { Personal Assistant }
  \\ \hline \text { Lightly Scorch } & \text { Calendars Lifespan }
  \\ \hline  
\end{array}

*I'm having fun with these tables, so if it doesn't show for any reason here is a CSV of the same:*

```
Shout,Echo
Past Curfew,Spike Drink
Vaccine Injection,Chimney Deposit    
Hearing Organs,Red Planet
First Prize,Castrate Horse        
Heavenly Body,Fly High          
High Temperature,Without Ice
Road Curve,Wrap Tightly       
Bacon Fat,Touch Down
Buy and...,Aquatic Clapper
Supply Meal,Ward Off
Money Maker,Watch Temporarily
Sharp Taste,Piece of
Stocking stuffers,Snooker Surface
Carnival attraction,Personal Assistant
Lightly Scorch,Calendars Lifespan
```

Comment: Calendars or Calanders?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - Spelling is decidedly not my strong point :) Corrected it now, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arranging the answers in columns, with the relevant letters next to them:

> [image]

Yielding

> Come on in and play.

Comment: well done! +1...

Comment: Great work @hdsdv - quickly solved, on the money.

Answer (score 4):

Logic:

> What you shout is a crossword clue. Find the answer, change one letter, and the echo is a crossword clue of the new word. The changed letter is in Caps.

Past Curfew, Spike Drink

> laTe, laCe

Vaccine Injection, Chimney Deposit

> sHot, soOt

Hearing Organs, Red Planet

> Ears, Mars

First Prize, Castrate Horse

> gOld, gEld

Heavenly Body, Fly High

High Temperature, Without Ice

> Heat, Neat

Road Curve, Wrap Tightly

> bEnd, bInd

Bacon Fat, Touch Down

> laRd, laNd

Buy and..., Aquatic Clapper

Supply Meal, Ward Off

> feEd, feNd

Money Maker, Watch Temporarily

Sharp Taste, Piece of

Stocking stuffers, Snooker Surface

> feEt, feLt

Carnival attraction, Personal Assistant

> Aide, Ride

Lightly Scorch, Calanders Lifespan

> Sear, Year

Then the answer can be extracted by

> looking for the changed letter of the new word, i.e. COME?NIN?N??LRY

Comment: Nice one @OmegaKrypton - definitely on the right track.

Comment: +1 from me too - sorry, I didn't see this until after I posted.