# Puzzle Hunt 03: As a bat

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, nonogram

---

<sub>This is part three in my clichéd treasure island puzzle series. The story carries directly on from [part two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90881/puzzle-hunt-02-echoes-of-change). Part one is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90823/puzzle-hunt-01-a-cliched-treasure-map). There may be a bit of a gap before part 4 as I'm running out of ideas :)</sub>

---

The message from the cave is clear - if somewhat ominous. With a slight chill of apprehension the three of you head into the cave. The gloom thickens and the humidity becomes palpable. The weak, pale light from your torches barely illuminate your passage. The darkness of the cave seems to take on a life and morbid personality of its own, defying sight, rendering you close to blind.

After feeling you way down the cave for what feels like an age, unexpectedly it turns a sharp corner and abruptly opens into a large room. Soft and surprisingly dry sand carpets the cavern. A beam of light from a small shaft in the caves ceiling provides some welcome illumination and respite from your temporary blindness. Partially submerged in the sand is a chest, with a large combination lock. There are 4 rotating disks with 26 faces holding letters instead of numbers. Clearly a 4 letter word is required to open this chest.

A further search of the room reveals a grid scratched into the top of a flat rock, and a collection of small, round pebbles beside it. Perhaps this grid provides a clue as to the password.

Can you solve the puzzle and find the word to open the chest?

[image: The puzzle grid]

Comment: can you check the nonogram? i think there are some errors. thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - rot13(Lbh jvyy abg or noyr gb fbyir gur ragver chmmyr hfvat genqvgvbany ababtenz ybtvp (be bayvar fbyiref) nybar, ohg vg fubhyq yrnir lbh jvgu rabhtu gb qrqhpr gur nafjre - vs lbh pna qrgrezvar jurer gb tb sebz gur cnegvny fbyhgvba.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this just robs the answer from @Jens and @Omega Krypton.

Jens has

> the correct solution to the nonogram.

Omega Krypton has

> The idea to treat each 2x3 box as a braille letter.

Now,

> If we combine these, interpereting filled squares as raised dots, we get the message
>  allthatglittersisnot

The 4 letter answer is

> GOLD. All that glitters is not GOLD.

Comment: Nice robbing! :-)

Comment: Great work all! Seems appropriate to the story that three people should solve the puzzle together! Right as rain, if I could give three ticks I would.

Answer (score 8):

**Partial**

> [image]

The four letters still escape me.

Comment: Nice job - so far so good

Answer (score 5):

### Partial

Solving the nonogram by hand (yellow clues don't match)

> [image]

Treating the grids as

> Braille alphabet

renders no result

Comment: Good start - but rot13(Lbh zvtug jnag gb purpx gung svefg ebj...)

Comment: aha @Johnson edited, better?

Comment: A bit better, but still some errors - rot13(V cynl grfgrq vg ol unaq n ahzore bs gvzrf (naq qbhoyr purpxrq jvgu n fbyire) naq lbh pna ernpu n cbvag jurer vg vf zbfgyl svyyrq, ohg fbzr fdhnerf jvgu zhygvcyr cbffvovyvgvrf (bayl n pbhcyr). V'z nsenvq V'z abg fher jurer lbh fgenlrq gubhtu... Ohg V cebzvfr gung vg jbexf!)

Comment: The '9' column means your interpretation of '1 1 1' is blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but here is my solution.

With some help from @Omega Krypton I solved it.

Solving the nonogram, multiple solutions:

> [image]

Applying the hint from @Omega Krypton:

> Treating each 2x3 box as braille yields these four solution:
> All that gletters is not
> All that glitter? is no?
> All that glitters is not
> All that gletter? is no?

This makes it possible to deduce the four letter word:

> All that glitters is not = GOLD

Comment: Left column and right column contain identical pictures (read vertically).