# Puzzle Hunt 06: Stepping Stones

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

---

<sub>This is part six in my clichéd treasure island puzzle series, but can be solved on its own. The story carries on from [part five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94585/puzzle-hunt-05-reading-between-the-lines).</sub>

---

Based on the information from the notebook, you at least know where to start. You head towards the sound of rushing water - briefly wondering what happened to your friends Frank and Joan - before deciding that they must not have been important enough to the plot to warrant keeping around.

You arrive at a densely bushed riverbed, and find a short path between the foliage to the riverside. Looking across the river you see another such path leading away a bit downstream. Bridging the river is a grid of perfectly flat almost square stepping stones, apparently engraved with some form of ancient hieroglyph.

*A top-down view of the situation - you are positioned at the clearing at the top of the picture.*

[image: Arial view of river crossing]

You take a look into the notebook to see if it has any wisdom to offer. There is a random and barely legible entry that looks like it might be related.

```
run run
o wot fu
n we so l
ight fl
y my two
son o ye
eh runn
```

Can you find a path across, and directions where to go next?

---

<sub>Attributions: All icons courtesy of [Icons8](https://icons8.com/)

Apologies: To all graphic designers out there offended by the multiple styles</sub>

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> NOW WEST, FOLLOW YOUR NOSE

This works as follows:

> For finding the path, we note that every icon corresponds to a word. Some of the words on adjacent tiles can be concatenated to form new words; for example the icon just below the entry point shows "honey", and the icon below this gives "moon", together giving "honeymoon". It turns out that we can make a path from the top of the river to the bottom of the river such that all consecutive words on the path form such a pair:
>
>  [image]
>
>  (Note that there are a lot of other pairs of icons that might also be linked, but this was the only path I was able to find.)
>  Now we still need to find where to go, but luckily, we still have the notebook entry! Each of the lines in this entry contains exactly 6 characters (excluding spaces), and there are seven lines. Coincidentally, there are also 7 rows of 6 stones each in the river, so it makes sense to link each character to one of the stones. This gives the following picture:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Reading off all the letters along the path gives the given answer.

Comment: Confirmed.  You beat me by a nose :)

Comment: Great answer! Perfectly explained and everything correct. The ? you put on the r13(cnq) icon is justified, I spent a little while searching for a better one, but the only other option was a r13(fnavgnel cnq) which I thought might be a bit crude...